# JSF 2 ManagedProperty injection of bean from dependency jar

Tags: java, jsf, dependency-injection, jsf-2

I'm trying to get a ManagedProperty injection working, where the injected bean resides in a jar included in my web application.

Bean to be injected:

```
@ManagedBean(name="messages")  
@SessionScoped  
public class Messages implements Serializable
{
```

Receiving bean:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{messages}")
private Messages messages;

public void setMessages(Messages messages)
{
    this.messages = messages;
}
```

However, this doesn't work and I'm just getting the message "Unable to set property messages for managed bean".
If I put the Messages class in the same package as the receiving bean instead of having it in it's own jar, it works just fine.

Answer (score 9):

The JAR must contain a JSF 2.0 compliant `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` file to trigger JSF 2.0 annotation scans in JAR files.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
</faces-config>
```